# Animate h1 tag from WordPress header.php using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to animate the site title (of my WordPress site in WAMP) that is generated by an `<h1>` tag in the header.php template of my WordPress child theme (I typed the site's title here: General -> Settings -> Site Title).

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="site-branding">
            <h1 class="site-title tlt"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </div>
```

I have identified this line as the one that generates my website's title:

```
<h1 class="site-title tlt"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
```

and have placed the class `tlt` in the `h1` tag for textillate (https://github.com/jschr/textillate) to do the animating. Textillate requires three dependencies (jQuery, lettering.js
animate.css) which I have linked to in head section of header.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/qwerty-child/vendors/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/wp-content/themes/qwerty-child/vendors/animate.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/qwerty-child/vendors/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/qwerty-child/script.js"></script>
```

I have even tried relative paths to all dependencies, like this

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vendors/animate.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendors/jquery.textillate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Still not animating. Finally, here is my jQuery script:

Note: my `script.js` file is up one directory from the others

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $('.tlt').textillate();
})
```

}

I read the codex about using JavaScript but I still could not get it to animate (https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript). I have used textillate before and it works well, however, this is the first time I'm using it on WordPress

Comment: there are well documented enqueuing procedures you should follow for adding scripts in wordpress. Most likely jQuery is already in page and you will cause problems putting it in again. Also read how noConflict() is used in wordpress. A simple check of errors in your browser console should show `$ is undefined`

Comment: +1 Ahhh... I got these errors from Chrome DevTools: `LastPass: Skipping form because submit is not a function!
http://localhost/wp-content/themes/qwerty-child/vendors/animate.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: All errors: `GET http://localhost/wp-content/themes/qwerty-child/vendors/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js 
localhost/:13 GET http://localhost/wp-content/themes/qwerty-child/vendors/animate.css 
localhost/:14 GET http://localhost/wp-content/themes/qwerty-child/vendors/jquery.textillate.js 
localhost/:15 GET http://localhost/wp-content/themes/qwerty-child/script.js 
VM10488:1 LastPass: Skipping form because submit is not a function!VM10488:1 (anonymous function)onloadwff.js:1027 run_custom_jsonloadwff.js:199 hookAllFormSubmitsonloadwff.js:193 evalScriptsInFrameonloadwff.js:194 (anonymous function)`

Comment: You really should write it as an plugin to wp. It is really ease.